# NotifyDataSetChanged or NotifyItemRemoved causing blank spaces and ghosting in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Recently, some users of my app have been reporting issues with items "sticking" in the RecyclerView background after my app executes notifyItemRemoved, notifyItemRangeRemoved, or notifyDataSetChanged on a RecyclerView.

I cannot reproduce this issue, but it seemed to start cropping up a few weeks after updating to the support version 23.3.0.

Examples from my users:

[image: ghosting]

[image: blank spaces]

[image: more ghosting]

Is it possibly the fact that my RecyclerView has no background color set, or could it be a bug with the v23.3.0 version of the RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the ItemAnimator I was using. Switching to another library fixed my issues.